How to insert multiple AVAssets into AVMutableCompositionTrack with silence in between?
I'm recording videos frame by frame and occasionally a sound plays (from an MP3 asset). I want to composite these sounds into the video at the correct timings. But this doesn't work. Really pulling my hair out here. I've tried everything, including adding one after another and then inserting silence in between (allegedly this pushes subsequent clips back) but nothing works.
Here, _currentTime is the current time according to the video frames added, which are added at 20Hz.
You can see I am adding silence long enough to cover the time from the end of the last audio clip to now, plus extra padding to contain the audio we are about to add. Doesn't matter if I remove this, it just doesn't work. Sometimes I can get two pieces of audio to play but never a third and usually, only the first audio plays, and then nothing after.
I'm completely stumped.
func addFrame(_ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        guard CGSize(width: pixelBuffer.width, height: pixelBuffer.height) == _outputSize else { return }

        let frameTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(_frameCount), timescale: _frameRate)

        if _videoInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
            _pixelBufferAdaptor?.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: frameTime)
            _frameCount += 1
            _currentTime = frameTime
        }
    }

    func addMP3AudioClip(_ audioData: Data) async throws {
        let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + ".mp3")
        defer {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempURL)
        }
        try audioData.write(to: tempURL)

        let asset = AVAsset(url: tempURL)
        let duration = try await asset.load(.duration)
        let audioTrack = try await asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .audio).first!

        // Insert silence
        var currentAudioTime = _currentTime.convertScale(duration.timescale, method: .default)
        if CMTimeCompare(_lastAudioClipEndTime, currentAudioTime) < 0 {
            // _lastAudioClipEndTime < currentAudioTime. Safe to insert silence. Sometimes, this is
            // not true due to some sort of timing mismatch and the time range ends up NaN if so.
            let precedingSilence = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: _lastAudioClipEndTime, end: currentAudioTime)
            _audioTrack?.insertEmptyTimeRange(precedingSilence)
            _audioTrack?.insertEmptyTimeRange(CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: currentAudioTime, end: CMTimeAdd(currentAudioTime, duration)))
            print("[VideoRecorder] \(currentAudioTime.seconds) \(duration.seconds) \(precedingSilence.start.seconds) \(precedingSilence.end.seconds) \(_lastAudioClipEndTime.seconds)")
        } else {
            currentAudioTime = _lastAudioClipEndTime
            _audioTrack?.insertEmptyTimeRange(CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: currentAudioTime, end: CMTimeAdd(currentAudioTime, duration)))
            print("[VideoRecorder] \(currentAudioTime.seconds) \(duration.seconds) \(_lastAudioClipEndTime.seconds)")
        }

        // Audio clip
        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: duration)
        try _audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: currentAudioTime)

        _lastAudioClipEndTime = CMTimeAdd(currentAudioTime, duration)
    }

For reference, the complete class is here:
//
//  VideoRecorder.swift
//  RoBart
//
//  Created by Bart Trzynadlowski on 10/2/24.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

actor VideoRecorder {
    private var _assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
    private var _videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    private var _audioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    private var _pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor?

    private var _frameCount: Int64 = 0
    private let _frameRate: Int32
    private let _outputSize: CGSize
    private var _currentTime: CMTime = .zero
    private var _lastAudioClipEndTime: CMTime = .zero

    private var _audioMixer: AVMutableComposition?
    private var _audioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack?

    init(outputSize: CGSize, frameRate: Int32) {
        self._outputSize = outputSize
        self._frameRate = frameRate
    }

    func startRecording() throws {
        let outputURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("output.mp4")
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)  // just in case we crashed and a file is still there
        _assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: .mp4)

        let videoSettings: [String: Any] = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey: _outputSize.width,
            AVVideoHeightKey: _outputSize.height,
        ]

        _videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
        _videoInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

        let rotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)   // vertical orientation
        _videoInput?.transform = rotationTransform

        let sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [String: Any] = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: _outputSize.width,
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: _outputSize.height
        ]

        _pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(
            assetWriterInput: _videoInput!,
            sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributes
        )

        let audioSettings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
        _audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
        _audioInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false // audio is composed into a track and copied to video when we finish recording
        _audioMixer = AVMutableComposition()
        _audioTrack = _audioMixer!.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        _assetWriter?.add(_videoInput!)
        _assetWriter?.add(_audioInput!)
        _assetWriter?.startWriting()
        _assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)

        _currentTime = .zero
        _lastAudioClipEndTime = .zero
    }

    func addFrame(_ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        guard CGSize(width: pixelBuffer.width, height: pixelBuffer.height) == _outputSize else { return }

        let frameTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(_frameCount), timescale: _frameRate)

        if _videoInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
            _pixelBufferAdaptor?.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: frameTime)
            _frameCount += 1
            _currentTime = frameTime
        }
    }

    func addMP3AudioClip(_ audioData: Data) async throws {
        let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + ".mp3")
        defer {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempURL)
        }
        try audioData.write(to: tempURL)

        let asset = AVAsset(url: tempURL)
        let duration = try await asset.load(.duration)
        let audioTrack = try await asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .audio).first!

        // Insert silence
        var currentAudioTime = _currentTime.convertScale(duration.timescale, method: .default)
        if CMTimeCompare(_lastAudioClipEndTime, currentAudioTime) < 0 {
            // _lastAudioClipEndTime < currentAudioTime. Safe to insert silence. Sometimes, this is
            // not true due to some sort of timing mismatch and the time range ends up NaN if so.
            let precedingSilence = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: _lastAudioClipEndTime, end: currentAudioTime)
            _audioTrack?.insertEmptyTimeRange(precedingSilence)
            _audioTrack?.insertEmptyTimeRange(CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: currentAudioTime, end: CMTimeAdd(currentAudioTime, duration)))
            print("[VideoRecorder] \(currentAudioTime.seconds) \(duration.seconds) \(precedingSilence.start.seconds) \(precedingSilence.end.seconds) \(_lastAudioClipEndTime.seconds)")
        } else {
            currentAudioTime = _lastAudioClipEndTime
            _audioTrack?.insertEmptyTimeRange(CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: currentAudioTime, end: CMTimeAdd(currentAudioTime, duration)))
            print("[VideoRecorder] \(currentAudioTime.seconds) \(duration.seconds) \(_lastAudioClipEndTime.seconds)")
        }

        // Audio clip
        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: duration)
        try _audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: currentAudioTime)

        _lastAudioClipEndTime = CMTimeAdd(currentAudioTime, duration)
    }

    func finishRecording() async throws {
        guard let videoInput = _videoInput,
              let audioInput = _audioInput,
              let audioMixer = _audioMixer,
              let audioTrack = _audioTrack else { return }

        // Video is finished
        videoInput.markAsFinished()
        print("[VideoRecorder] Total video length: \(_currentTime.seconds)")

        // Write audio
        let audioOutputSettings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,  // convert to PCM from MP3
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
            AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false
        ]
        let audioReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: audioMixer)
        let audioReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioTrack, outputSettings: audioOutputSettings)
        audioReader.add(audioReaderOutput)
        audioReader.startReading()

        // Read the audio from the track we composed and add it to the video
        while audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
            if let sampleBuffer = audioReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
                audioInput.append(sampleBuffer)
            } else {
                audioInput.markAsFinished()
                break
            }
        }

        // Write the asset file and save it to the photo library
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            _assetWriter?.finishWriting {
                if let error = self._assetWriter?.error {
                    print("[VideoRecorder] Error writing asset file: \(error)")
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                } else if let outputURL = self._assetWriter?.outputURL {
                    self.saveVideoToPhotoLibrary(outputURL: outputURL) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("[VideoRecorder] Error saving video: \(error)")
                            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                        } else {
                            continuation.resume()
                            print("[VideoRecorder] Saved video to photo library")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: NSError(domain: "VideoCreatorError", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unknown error occurred"]))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func saveVideoToPhotoLibrary(outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL)
        }) { success, error in
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
            if success {
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

